# Blazor deploying project in IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, blazor, server-side

Hello i have an error said "he Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app."

and i already done some configs like changing it into Development and still nothing error coming out in google chrome console

```
 "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "nativeDebugging": false
    },
    "BlazorLog": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"` to `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"`.

Otherwise, you can update the web.config like this:

```
 <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
  </environmentVariables>
```